# Android Studio 3.5 deploy issue on my smartphone

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated my Android Studio to 3.5 and I am starting to use the new "Apply Changes" feature. I can deploy my apps without problems using AVD, but when I use my smartphone (Galaxy S9+ with Oreo) the process keeps crashing and all the times I have to kill manually the app and click Start.

I've already tried to create a new project, kill all the apps, plug & unplug the USB cable and restart my device. I tried also Invalidate cache/restart and clean project.

This is the error that the IDE gives me:

> E/zygote64: Bad JNI version passed to GetEnv: 805372416 
>   E/studio.deploy: Error retrieving JVMTI function table. 
>   Changes were not applied. 
>   We were unable to deploy your changes: MISSING_AGENT_RESPONSES

Thanks for your help

After contacting the Google Team they have opened a new issue, here's the link if you want to stay updated: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139942372

UPDATE: Google has marked this issue as fixed, I think that in the next update everything will be fine.

Comment: Android Studio 3.5 does not have Instant Run. It has a new "Apply Changes" set of options. Which toolbar button or Run menu option are you using to try running your app, that gives you these results?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't remember the name. The options that aren't working are "Apply Changes and restart activity" and "Apply Code changes"

Comment: From the error message, it feels like perhaps your app is using the NDK (directly or through a library), and that Apply Changes is having problems with it. My guess is that this is an IDE bug. If you are in position to try to create a reproducible test case, you might consider filing an issue. Otherwise... don't click those toolbar buttons. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Well, in my app I am using Retrofit, Anko and some Material UI Libraries, I don't know which of them can cause the problem. I am quite new to android but if I won't receive an answer I surely signal this issue. Yes, I can still run my app in the old way but I'd like to know why this is happening. Never stop learning :)

Comment: "I don't know which of them can cause the problem" -- none of those should be using JNI/NDK binaries. You might want to create a new scrap project from the Android Studio new-project wizard. Then, try running it using those Apply Changes options on your device. If you get the same problem, then it is more likely to be specific to that device model. In that case, you might want to file an issue, identifying what model your device is and explaining what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is happening with a plain project, my guess is that there is some incompatibility between your device and the "Apply Changes" feature in Android Studio 3.5.

[This issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139782876) seems to match your symptoms. Keep an eye on it, and with luck this will get fixed in Android Studio 3.5.1, either by fixing the IDE or at least detecting that "Apply Changes" will not work and reacting better.

Comment: Hi, i have followed this issue and the Google Team told me that our cases were different, so they opened a new issue just for me. I have updated my question.